# How to include git changelog w/ email with jenkins since last successful build?

Tags: git, jenkins, changelog, email-ext

This is what I've tried:

1. Jenkins manages the repository.
2. Add a post-build step: Publish git changelog from: $GIT_PREVIOUS_SUCCESSFUL_COMMIT to $GIT_SUCCESS -  Inside the Jenkins task-console I can see the correct output.
3. Added $GITCHANGELOG to my output email content - its always "No revs given, searching automatically for latest released tags..." with a very long log following.

What am I doing wrong ? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From version 2.0 of [Git Changelog Plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/git-changelog-plugin), you can get the changelog as a String in a pipeline. And you can specify from/to references to reduce the included commits.